# In-memory ActiveRecord for production use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, redmine

I'm currently extending some functionality from Redmine 1.4 issue tracker (it uses Rails 2.3.14 and Ruby 1.8.7).

One thing I don't really like about it for my current use case is that some classes that encapsulate business logic (roles, workflows) are database based instead of code based - our customer shouldn't be able to change roles and workflows without our intervention, and while I could just preload a pre-baked set of db data with the roles and workflows I want, I still think it would be a solution which is not the best for maintainability's sake.

What I'd like to do is something like that:

```
class Person < SomeInMemoryActiveRecordBaseClass
end

p = Person.new(:name => "Somebody)
p.save
```

And then I'd like to be able to invoke ActiveRecord methods on any Person object and from the Person class, even though there's no real database behind it.

This may seem a silly thing to do (If I were creating the project from scratch I'd simply not use an AR-based object, but since I'm building on something that already exists this is not an option), but the objects I need to work with in-memory are used in plenty of places and they're supposed to be AR-based; changing their usage everywhere would really be time consuming.

I've seen some projects, like [nulldb](https://github.com/nulldb/nulldb), which are test-oriented, not production-oriented, and they don't implement all methods. Besides that, the AR interface seems quite sql-oriented and I don't know if it's really feasible to get an sql-emulation layer "right".

Is there any library that could suit my use-case of creating a fully-functional activerecord in-memory database?

(I've already thought about using a different connection and leveraging an inmemory sqlite db, but it seems a bit overengineered to me).

Comment: The appropriate way to handle the problem is to put it in your contract. "The customer shall not modify or change or access data directly in the database, except through the provided GUI" or something along those lines. Otherwise, they'll hack it somehow and you won't have any fall back if they break things.

Comment: My problem is not with the contract; I could disable workflow management entirely, even remove the pages from the GUI. Mine was a technical doubt.